# set title of option tag with its text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select tag with id as try. I need to set the title of each of its option tag with its text.How to do it..Below is the code i have tried..

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="try">
<option value="1">Option #1</option>
<option value="2">Option #2</option>
<option value="3">Option #3</option>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$("#try option").each(function(name, val) {
    var opt=val.text;
    $(this).attr({"title":opt});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `each()`, jQuery methods do that automatically; so I'd suggest:

```
$('#try option').prop('title', function(){
  return this.text;
});
```

```js
$('#try option').prop('title', function() {
  return this.text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="try">
  <option value="1">Option #1</option>
  <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  <option value="3">Option #3</option>
</select>
```

Or, in plain, JavaScript:

```
// using Function.prototype.call() to iterate over
// the Array-like NodeList returned from
// Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#try option'), function(optionEl) {

  // setting the title property to the value of the text property:
  optionEl.title = optionEl.text;
});
```

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#try option'), function(optionEl) {
  optionEl.title = optionEl.text;
});
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" id="try">
  <option value="1">Option #1</option>
  <option value="2">Option #2</option>
  <option value="3">Option #3</option>
</select>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: Didn't knew about that. +1

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, Harshini; I'm glad to have been of help! And, @Tushar, every day in which we learn something is a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of current option use `text`:

```
$("#try option").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", $(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, but instead of

```
$(this).attr({"title":opt});
```

do

```
$(this).attr("title",opt);
```

(without the curly braces and `:`)

```js
$("#try option").each(function(name, val) { var opt=val.text;
                                           console.log(opt);
                                      $(this).attr("title",opt);
                                     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="try">
<option value="1">Option #1</option>
<option value="2">Option #2</option>
<option value="3">Option #3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No, an [object can be used to set property-value pairs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#setting-several-attrs).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, are you sure you want to add a title tag on the  tag?

here is a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/jcopreaj/

```
$("#try option").each(function(name, val) { 
  var opt=val.text;
  $(this).attr({"title":opt});
});
```

Comment: [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) is *not*, in any way, 'deprecated,'  and [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) is a different method (for performing a similar task), it's not a replacement.